# Excel Power Query for REST API with pagination

Tags: excel, rest, powerquery, m

I have an Excel (15225.20356) Power Query that pulls data from a REST API. I have no trouble getting the first page of data (50 results). But, I'm struggling with writing the for-loop to generate a list with the full results.

The JSON I receive from the first query looks like this:

```
{
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "isLast": false,
    "values": [...]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this C code in Power Query

```
struct Results {
    int maxResults;
    int startAt;
    BOOL isLast;
    Values values;
};

Results result;
List list;
for(int result_count = 0; 
    result.isLast == FALSE; 
    result_count += result.maxResults) {
    try {
        result.startAt = result_count;
        GetNextResult(&result);
        list.insert(&result); // taking some liberties in the translation from PQ to pseudo-C here
    } 
    catch (...) {
        break;
    }
}
```

My attempt in Power Query looks like this

```
let
    GetNextResult=(start as number) =>
    let
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://my.jira.server/rest/agile/latest/board/8479/sprint",[Query=[startAt=Number.ToText(start)]]))
    in
        Source,

    GetAllResults=()=>
    let
        AllResults = List.Generate(()=> 
            [result_count=0, Result = GetNextResult(0)],
            each [Result][isLast] <> false,
            each [result_count=[Result][maxResults], Result = GetNextResult(result_count)],
            each [Result][values])
    in
        AllResults

in
    GetAllResults
```

This results in an empty list.
How do I generate a results list from multiple queries to the REST API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to debug without access to the API but I can spot a couple of mistakes.

```
 each [result_count=[Result][maxResults], Result = GetNextResult(result_count)],
```

According to Jira docs, maxResults is just the number of results per page so no need to track or adjust this property.

Try something like this.

```
   each [result_count= [result_count]+50, Result = GetNextResult(Text.From(result_count))],
```

Everything else looks ok to me.

Comment: To debug a query, you can write request errors to the log file using [WebRequest.DebugInfo.pq](https://github.com/ninmonkey/ninMonkQuery-examples/blob/96fd33ab255ceeccacc6f67048c9d2377ed6e21f/forumQuestions/pq/WebRequest.DebugInfo.pq#L20-L85) -- that gives you extra debug info in the editor as well, [see the screenshot](https://github.com/ninmonkey/ninMonkQuery-examples/blob/main/forumQuestions/img/Web.Contents%20%20-%20RelativePath%20paging%20and%20default%20values%20%E2%81%9E%202023-08-02.2023-09-04%20122419.png?raw=true)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue today and this formula worked for me for the *AllResults* part:

```
AllResults = List.Generate(
    () => [startAt = 0, Result = GetNextResult(issuekey,startAt)],
    each [startAt] < [Result][total],
    each [startAt = [startAt]+[Result][maxResults], Result = GetNextResult(issuekey,startAt)],
    each [Result][values]
),
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33468428)